# Align two panels side by side to cover the whole screen (ExtJS 6.2.0)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have this Panel

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboardPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
     
    xtype: 'basic-panels',

   
    controller: 'newDashboard',


     
    layout: 'fit',...
```

and have created this Container :

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.newDashboard',
  
    controller: 'newDashboard',
    reference: 'dashboard',

    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        align: 'stretch '
    },
    height: 620,

    style: {
        'backgroundColor': '#909090 !important'
    },

    items: [{
           
           
            region: 'west',
            xtype: 'panel',
            //margin: '5 0 0 5',


            width: 200,
            collapsible: true, // make collapsible
            id: 'west-region-container',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'settingsMenu2'

            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'basic-panels',
           layout: 'fit'
        }
    ]


});
```

The latter code is to create the main view which is a sidebar and the `Mine.view.newDashboardPanel` panel My problem is that the panel (xtype basic-panels) doesn't cover its whole allocated space and therefore `Mine.view.newDashboard` doesn't cover the screen.
How to achieve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: add `layout: 'fit',...` to the basic-panel's parent component. or maybe basic-panel is your main component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that specify region:'center'

```
{
    xtype: 'basic-panels',
    region: 'center'
}
```

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.newDashboard',

    controller: 'newDashboard',
    reference: 'dashboard',

    layout: 'border',
    height: 620,

    style: {
        'backgroundColor': '#909090 !important'
    },

    items: [{

        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        //margin: '5 0 0 5',

        width: 200,
        collapsible: true, // make collapsible
        id: 'west-region-container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'settingsMenu2'

        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'basic-panels',
        region: 'center'
    }]

});
```

Comment: YES, That was it. but coming to the height it's not exactly it, as i had to specify the height of 620px is there any way of making the height fitting the screen as well ?

Comment: if you want to specify the height you are right layout border will not work. use layout hbox to align  panels side by side